# TextBox.Text returns nothing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a tab control on it, and on one of these tabs, I have a `ComboBox`.  Depending on the value the user selects in this `ComboBox`, different controls need to populate.  This is working fine, however, when I attempt to retrieve the text the user has put into a `TextBox` control that I have populating, `TextBox.Text` returns nothing to me.  `TextBox.Text` works fine when I add a `TextBox` to the same form, but include it in the form initialization (rather than populating it on the form later with the method below), which makes me think I am missing a property on the control.

- I am not wanting to populate the control with text in it, I want the string that the user enters in runtime - I want to use `TextBox.Text` to obtain that value, not the value of a string I already have in the control.

Snippet from the method I'm using to populate the `TextBox` and other controls onto the tab control:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox filePathBox;

private void populateControls(string someText)
    {
        if (someText == "Something")
        {
            // 
            // TextBox
            //
            this.filePathBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 61);
            this.filePathBox.Name = "filePathBox";
            this.filePathBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 20);

            this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.filePathBox);
            this.filePathBox.Show();
        }
        else if (someText == "SomethingElse")
        {
            //populate other controls.
        }
    }
```

And, to test, I have a button that simply displays a `MessageBox` of the string that is in the `TextBox`, which results in nothing.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(filePathBox.Text);
    }
```

Again, it makes me think I am missing some properties from the `TextBox`, but anything would be appreciated at this point.

Comment: Isn't your textbox set up in the `InitializeComponent` from the constructor? and also, where are you setting the `Text`property?

Comment: I don't see where you set `Text` property. Why there should be something?

Comment: Are you sure the user types in the textbox you think he/she is? You could set the `BackColor` property to something different to see. Also - if `populateControls()` is called more than once, you may be overwriting the filePathBox variable (you didn't mention where you create the instance) while adding multiple boxes to the tab.

Comment: Even though all the controls are populated depending on what the user has selected in a dropdown, should I still be creating the instance of these controls in InitializeComponent()?  If so, wouldn't that result in a lot of memory being used on different sets of controls that aren't being used?

I'm not setting the Text property anywhere. I only want the user's input, and want the control blank on load.

Comment: Check where is `this.filePathBox=new TextBox()`, and make sure it will not be called multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your:

```
this.filePathBox = new TextBox();
```

to:

```
if(this.filePathBox==null)
{
    this.filePathBox = new TextBox();  
}
```

Comment: Even though all the controls are populated depending on what the user has selected in a dropdown, should I still be creating the instance of these controls in InitializeComponent()? If so, wouldn't that result in a lot of memory being used on different sets of controls that aren't being used?

Comment: Thanks. Are components automatically declared and initialized in the Designer.cs file in every WinForms project?

Comment: @thewhitehorserider, yes, if the components are dragged on to the 'Form' in design mode.

Comment: Didn't think I dragged this control in design mode, but I must have. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you correctly initialized filePathBox in your `InitializeComponents()` (form designer content) so... the filePathBox.Text will be initially empty. You have to fill it with content before it shows something... like this:

```
filePathBox.Text = "something";
MessageBox.Show(filePathBox.Text);
```

Comment: Don't want anything in the control when it populates.  Only want to take the users input and do something with that.

Comment: Yes but if the user entered nothing in the TB how can you pretend its text content to be different from nothing? If you click the button before filling the TB, you will se nothing from MessageBox...

Comment: Yes - sorry, I should have explicitly implied this.  I get nothing from TextBox.Text even after the user has entered something runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick sample and saw no issues. Make sure your constructor calls InitializeComponents,hope this helps

```
 private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox filePathBox = new TextBox();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateControls("Something");
    }

    public void PopulateControls(string someText)
    {
        if (someText == "Something")
        {

            this.filePathBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 61);
            this.filePathBox.Name = "filePathBox";
            this.filePathBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 20);

            this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.filePathBox);
            this.filePathBox.Show();
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (filePathBox != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(filePathBox.Text);
        }
    }
```